# How to print an html table to pdf?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

Consider this simple example

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]

# HTML table
kable(dt, format = "html", caption = "Demo Table") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped",
                full_width = F) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2[note]" = 2)) %>%
  add_footnote(c("table footnote"))
```

[image]

Here I want a very simple thing. To print this table in a `pdf` (possibly in a pipe-able way). I want the table to look exactly like this.

I know this is `html`, but arent we able to print `html` pages to `pdf` in chrome? There has to be a way (I hope). I do not want to deal with latex and I do not want to create an `rnotebook` document. The rendering has to come from my bare .R script. Is that impossible?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to part of your problem of generating a table in pdf form. You will need to tweak the styling of your table in `xtable` in order to get the zebra stripe you want and merged columns. Generally speaking conversion from html to pdf is not so straightforward, so a better solution is to use LaTeX to generate your table in the first place (I know you didn't want LaTeX, but at least this is compiled to pdf with R and `xtable` does the hard work):

```
library(xtable)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]
filename <- tempfile(fileext = ".tex")
capture.output(print(xtable(dt)), file = filename)
foo <- readLines(filename)
writeLines(c("\\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}",
             "\\begin{document}",
             foo,
             "\\end{document}"),
           con = filename)
tools::texi2dvi(filename, pdf = TRUE)
```

You should have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf to get your styling the way you want it. Good luck.

Edit:
Seems you can use `kabelExtra` too:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]

# LaTeX table
a <- kable(dt, format = "latex", caption = "Demo Table") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped",
                full_width = F) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2[note]" = 2)) %>%
    add_footnote(c("table footnote"))

filename <- tempfile(fileext = ".tex")
capture.output(a, file = filename)
foo <- readLines(filename)
writeLines(c("\\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}",
             "\\begin{document}",
             foo,
             "\\end{document}"),
           con = filename)
tools::texi2dvi(filename, pdf = TRUE)
```

Comment: It seems `kabelExtra` can also output to LaTeX so you could maybe use your original code and follow the instructions here:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf